# How can I alias a path to another without the user knowing that path?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I thought I could do this with rewrite but I can't seem to find any information on it. What I want to do is this.

/path/to/my/program/index.php

I want to use a link for the use such as.

/forum/index.php

Is this posible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you're using apache as webserver [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) might be feasible.
Depending on what you want to achieve it may also be that a simple [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive would do the trick.

```
Alias /forum /path/to/my/program
```

Comment: Hi VolkerK. Thanks. When I was searching for the answer, I also came across this from the Apache site. Didn't understand it though. :(

Comment: VolkerK, I just tried this and nothing. I restarted apache but it will won't work. First, I had put this in the htaccess file and got a 500 server error. I then moved it into the httpd.conf file and tested the configuration with no errors but it will not work. Would you know why?

Comment: Volker, thanks. I got it working with the Alias directive. The reason I couldn't get it to work is because I was missing the quotes.

Comment: I'm currently on a windows machine and will need to change it later when I upload the site and will obviously no longer have to worry about the quotes.

Comment: Do you have a space in one of the directory names? Otherwise you shouldn't need the quotes. You can even use forward-slashes on a windows machine, e.g. `Alias /x d:/xampp/htdocs/public/x`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEgnine on
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*) path/to/my/program/$1 [L]
```

That will rewrite any request that’s URL path starts with `/forum/…` to the same but starting with `/path/to/my/program/…`.

Comment: Thank you Gumbo. Let me give that a try. brb.

Comment: @Jim: If your path is an absolute file system path, use it with the leading slash.

Comment: No Gumbo, nothing.. It doesn't work. I checked the path twice and it is correct.

Comment: @Jim: And mod_rewrite is available on your server?

Comment: Yes. I'm using it already with a couple of other rules. Its really weird because I commented out what I already had in the htaccess file and just left yours in and it will not work. I did just now manage to get it working with apache's alias directive BUT... I'd rather use mod_rewrite if possible. Would you have any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: @Jim: Where do you use that rule?

Comment: You mean the rule for the forum? I have it in the htaccess file in the directory root. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Gumbo, I noticed something... Maybe I'm wrong but shouldn't there be a dollar sign after the closing paran? Like this: ^forum/(.*)$

Comment: @Jim: No, in this case there is no difference whether you specify the end of the URL path or not. `.*` will match everything up to the end.

Comment: Ah, ok.. Thanks. Well, what do you think? Should I just stay with the Alias directive or do you think there is still hope to get this working with mod_rewrite?